# Add single quote to value

Tags: php, html

I have a script like this

```
<script>
function myFunction(name)
{
document.getElementById("peep").innerHTML = "Rule " + name;
}
</script>
```

Normally i would do something like this.

```
<button onclick="myFunction('Attacking cost 5 engery')"> Attack </button>
```

notice the '' around bob, but I dont know how to add them to this php variable.

```
<button onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $desc?>)"><?php echo $name; ?></button>
```

EDIT How i got $desc and $name

```
<php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM db_Rules");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 $desc = $row['desc'];
 $name = $row['rule'];
?>
<button onclick="myFunction('/<?php echo $desc;?>/')"><?php echo $name; ?></button>
<br>
<?php
 }
?>
```

Comment: use `\'` to add single qoute.

Comment: try "myFunction('<?php echo $desc?>')"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$name = "Attack";
$desc = "Attack costs 5 energy.";

?>
```

Let's take a look what happens if the PHP code gets executed:

```
button onclick="myFunction(Attack costs 5 energy.)">Attack</button>
```

That code doesn't work. You need to include some quotes in the Javascript function:

```
button onclick="myFunction('<?php echo $desc; ?>')"><?php echo $name; ?></button>
```

---

If you apply inserting PHP tags into HTML code many times, the code will get messy. So an alternative might be that you create a kind of custom parameters, for example, like this:

```
button onclick="myFunction('%description%')">%name%</button>
```

And then get PHP to replace it with the actual description and action name.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution for this problem is to *use appropriate escaping functions*.

You have a string that you want to insert into JavaScript and then insert that JavaScript into an HTML attribute.

First use `json_encode` to escape the string for JS. Since JSON is (more-or-less) a subset of JS, this will escape it suitably.

Then use `htmlspecialchars` to escape the resulting string for HTML.

```
myFunction(<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($desc)); ?>)
```

This will give you `&quot;` rather than `'`, but the effect will be the same.

It will also deal with input that has other characters that need escaping (such as new lines) and more complex data structures (arrays or objects).

Comment: looks like it's not on php page try http://testrules.site90.net/ and inspect element

Comment: `onclick="myFunction('&lt;?php echo $desc;?&gt;')"` — There is no way the code in this answer could result in that.

Answer (score 0):

simply add `''` to `<?php ?>` tag try

```
  <button onclick="myFunction('<?php echo $desc;?>')">
```

Comment: when i do that, i get the result `Rule` and the var $desc is never shown. Just to make sure i was getting the $desc i changed button name to $desc and it was showing up on the button.

Comment: so have you still any issue?

Comment: http://testrules.site90.net/   you can see it only shows the rules (well now it has been changed to description). So it is never showing this actual part after description

Comment: looks like you are not in .php page else you will get output :- <button onclick="myFunction('Attack costs 5 energy.')">Attack</button>

Comment: still kind of new to this. but it will run the php to connect to the db.

Comment: if you gone to inspect element you will find php code rather value means php not running on this page or you maked code as a string can you show your file name with extension

Comment: I am using a site builder thing, but it has option to insert html.  When i do this i start by connection to db threw php code. and `$name` is assigned threw a php while loop. So i know it is running the php..but maybe due to it not having a .php page.. thats why the code is not working?

Comment: what you currenlty have gives me `<button onclick="myFunction('&lt;?php echo $desc;?&gt;')">raze</button>`

Answer (score -1):

```
<button onclick="myFunction('<?php echo mysql_real_escape_string($desc);?>')">
<?php echo $name;?>
</button>
```

Comment: Even if `mysql_real_escape_string` wasn't deprecated, it wouldn't be appropriate to use here as the data is being inserted into JS and HTML, not MySQL.

Comment: No pb, the user cans use addslashes() instead of.